# Вывести из БД время без секунд

Tags: php, mysql

В базе данных хранится время в формате 11:00:00
Мне же при выводе секунды не нужны, поэтому использую при выводе след. функцию:

```
  printf('<td>%s</td>', date('G:i',$myrow['time']));
```

Но на любые значения, которые лежат в базе , выводит 4:00
Как это исправить?
В базе тип стоит time

Comment: А можно ли просто преобразовать данное время в текст, и обрезать какой-нибудь функцией ненужные символы?

Comment: @Радик Камалов, да, можно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Читайте внимательно какие аргументы принимает функция [`date`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php).

Comment: Сделал в базе тип varchar, все равно выводит 4:00

Comment: Чтобы Ваш код заработал как нужно, необходимо тип поля `time` изменить на `bigint`, а значение этого поля должно иметь дату в формате unix timestamp.